# why shipyard docker container does not start?

Tags: docker

I used the below docker command for install shipyard

```
$ docker create --name shipyard-rethinkdb-data shipyard/rethinkdb

$ docker run -it -d --name shipyard-rethinkdb --restart=always --volumes-from shipyard-rethinkdb-data -p 49153:8080 -p 49154:28015 -p 29015:29015 shipyard/rethinkdb

$ docker run -it -d --name shipyard -p 8080:8080 --link shipyard-rethinkdb:rethinkdb shipyard/shipyard
```

The problem is **shipyard** container does not start

```
[bu@bu ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                         NAMES
bac72c61bdd4        shipyard/rethinkdb   "/usr/bin/rethinkdb -"   25 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:29015->29015/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49153->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->28015/tcp   shipyard-rethinkdb
[bu@bu ~]$ docker start shipyard
shipyard
[bu@bu ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                         NAMES
bac72c61bdd4        shipyard/rethinkdb   "/usr/bin/rethinkdb -"   26 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:29015->29015/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49153->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49154->28015/tcp   shipyard-rethinkdb
```

System Details:

**OS** : Fedora 23 64 bit

**Docker Version** : 1.12.3

Answer (score 2):

Since your problem is that the container is not starting, it would be useful to see whatever message it displayed before dying. To see this, I simply removed the -d parameter from your command

```
$ docker run -it --name shipyard -p 8080:8080 --link shipyard-rethinkdb:rethinkdb shipyard/shipyard
NAME:
   shipyard - composable docker management

USAGE:
   controller [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   3.1.0 (8edbeac)

COMMANDS:
    server  run shipyard controller

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --debug, -D      enable debug
   --help, -h       show help
   --version, -v    print the version
```

Therefore, you should start the container with the server command.